# Use remote get to call API

Tags: php, wordpress

Not sure if this should go here or on the WordPress bit, will post it there if it's off topic :)

I'm trying to call an API (PHP newbie) and I'm completely stuck on how to proceed?? This is what I have so far...

```
class MyClass  {
private static $instance = null; 

protected function __construct() {
}

private function __clone() {}
private function __wakeup() {}

public static function getInstance() {
  if (self::$instance == null)  {
     self::$instance = new self;
    }     
    return self::$instance;
  } 

//Make the request
private function fetch_data($body) {
   // Do we have this information in our transients already?
  $transient = get_transient( 'fetch_data' );  

  // Yep!  Just return it and we're done.
  if( ! empty( $transient ) ) {              
    // The function will return here every time after the first time it is run, until the transient expires.
    return $transient;          
  // Nope!  We gotta make a call.
  } else { 
  $api_url = "https://someapi.co.uk/api";
  $request = wp_safe_remote_get(  $api_url );
  $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_safe_remote_get( $request ));

  // Save the API response so we only call every hour
  set_transient('fetch_data', '$body', 900);
    if( is_wp_error( $request ) ) {
      echo 'Something went wrong!';
      return false; // Bail early
    }
    else
    {
      $my_data = json_decode( $body, true );
    }   
    return $my_data;  
  }
  }
}
MyClass::getInstance();
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

On another page I include the file where the class is

```
include(locate_template(('modules/my-api-bridge.php'), false, false));
```

and use this

```
$my_data = MyClass::getInstance();
```

When I var dump I get this back

```
object(MyClass)#3894 (0) {
}
```

I try and use the variable like this

```
echo $my_data['Itinary'] ['ItineraryDetails'] ['Name']
```

I get this error message

```
FATAL ERROR: UNCAUGHT ERROR: CANNOT USE OBJECT OF TYPE MyClass AS ARRAY
```

I assumed that json_decode($body, true) would convert the JSON object to a PHP array?

So I try and access the object like this

```
echo $my_data->Itinary->ItineraryDetails->Name
```

I get this error message

```
Notice: Undefined property: MyClass::$Itinary in...
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in... 
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in...
```

Something is obviously amiss and I can't see what? Again, if this is more suited to the WordPress site then I'll repost it there :)

Comment: maybe i'm missing it, but when and where is fetch_data() called ?

Comment: not sure :/ would I need to call that for it to work?  Apologies if it's a dumb question lol.  New to this

Comment: Right now you only have an “empty” object, as the var_dump output clearly shows …

Comment: Ok, makes sense.  How do I pass the data?  Is it the API call that's wrong then?

Comment: You are using '$my_data = json_decode( $body, true );' which converts object/s into associative array/s. But you are referencing the variable '$my_data' as object by using "echo $my_data->Itinary->ItineraryDetails->Name". Since you parsed it into an array you will to have reference it as $my_data['Itinary']['ItineraryDetails']['Name'].

Comment: @zipkundan I have tried that method (see my post above).  I originally copied the JSON data to a file to get the displaying of the content to work (success) but now I try via the API and it doesn't work anynmore.  I want the data to be assed as an array but I thik there's a fault in my API call.

Comment: So, can anybody help?  Thanks

Comment: Your code is, $request = wp_safe_remote_get(  $api_url );
  $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body(wp_safe_remote_get( $request ));. You are using 'wp_safe_remote_get' twice. With 'wp_remote_retrieve_body' you should be using your '$request' variable instead of 'wp_safe_remote_get'.

Comment: hi @zipkundan, i have changed it to this...  $request = wp_safe_remote_get(  $api_url );  $body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request ); is this correct?  If so, it never worked?

Comment: Yes, this is correct way. Did you try to 'var_dump($body)'?
I would try var_dump($request) as the first step and then var_dump($body).
Apart from this I would also suggest to try and tes the API calls with "Postman". 
"https://www.getpostman.com/postman" 
Thats an easy and handy way to check the API requests. It also provides working code of the request in various scripting languages (e.g. php) which you can use directly in your project.